# ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate Issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

My List picker contains a lot of items.So I used FullModeItemTemplate:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,14"
                   FontSize="30"
                   Foreground="White"
                   Text="{Binding localizefamilyLabel}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
```

The problem is when navigating from it and back to it again.
I can open it, then navigate to another view.When I navigate back, it corrupted, items rearranged contains spaces.

What must I do to find it arranged when navigating again to this list?

Regards,

Comment: was it your ListPicker ItemSource change when you navigating back ?

Comment: No, the same ItemSource and the Data is already exist but not arranged, group of items then empty space then group of items and when I click on it, an item selected what ever I press into item or empty space.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the set items source code in the OnNavigatedTo event?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    listPicker.ItemsSource = // Source
}
```

If you do this, the page will reset the ListPicker items, so items will rearranged.
Wish this can help you.